# Using only 1 ScriptEngine in IronPython

Tags: c#, ironpython

We are using Ironpython in order to run Python from c#.
Our requirement is to run multiple scripts at the same time or one after the other.
We are using one ScriptEngine, and multiple ScriptScopes.

Creation of engine:

```
Dictionary<string, object> options = new Dictionary<string, object>();
options["Debug"] = true;
options["Frames"] = true;
m_engine = Python.CreateEngine(options);
```

After that, each time we run  script we use the following code:

```
ScriptSource script;
CompiledCode code;
ScriptScope scope;
 scope = m_engine.CreateScope();
script = m_engine.CreateScriptSourceFromFile(filePath);
code = script.Compile();
foreach (KeyValuePair<String, object> kvp in vars)
{
    scope.SetVariable(kvp.Key, kvp.Value);
}
code.Execute(scope);
```

When we use one scriptEngine and multiple scriptScope, we get the variables of the first scope in all the other scripts that are run.

We tried to run multiple engines, each script has its own variable array.
Is that the best way to handle multiple scripts? Is there a way that we can use the same engine in order to do that? We are taking a performance hit each time a new engine is created.

The script uses the Python reload command

Thanks

Comment: Hi @Mr. T. - did you ever solve this? I'm looking for a way to attach also a different logger per script scope.

Comment: Hi @DirkBoer, no we did not. Good luck to you.